# Asound fails to play a sound

Tags: c++, ubuntu, alsa, archlinux

I’m trying to use asound to play some sound in C++, but I’m stick with this error:

`Rate doesn't match (requested 44100Hz, get 0Hz)`

I tested my program on an Ubuntu and it works, but definitely fails on my archlinux.

Any idea?

Comment: I'd guess there's something wrong with your code ...

Comment: I figured it out, it was my .asound configuration file, I lacked it. Sorry.